# Including graphics files from a tar or zip

Tags: graphics

I'm wondering whether there is any way to include images that are in an archive. My reason for this is that I have a project where a very large number of sprites are used (each in different versions). Having several thousand image files is a bit of a hassle as, e.g., a copy of the project within the file system takes a long time. It would be much more convenient to have all images packaged together (potentially one package per version).

There is currently no way to do something like:

```
\includegraphics{VendorA.tar?1F600.png}
```

or

```
\graphicspath{ {VendorA.tar} {VendorB.zip} }
```

Is something like this impossible or could there be a way to add this?

**Edit:** 
I accepted Sergei's answer as that indeed  is an option. Still am curious as to whether this could be done in tex (or maybe luatex) without having to rely on the operating system. Mounting a zip does require some setup and can be a bit of a hassle if different users on different machine work on a document.

Comment: There is no possibilities to compile the TeX file when figures are in zip folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly include graphics from an archive file, but you can mount an archive into a directory using, for example `fuse-zip` and include graphics from the mounted directory. For example, the following works for me in Debian linux:

```
$ cat test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{figures/figure1.png}
\includegraphics{figures/figure1.png}
\end{document}
$ unzip -l figures.zip
Archive:  figures.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    43345  2016-12-22 16:11   figure1.png
    43345  2016-12-22 16:11   figure2.png
---------                     -------
    86690                     2 files
$ mkdir figures
$ ls figures
./  ../
$ fuse-zip -r figures.zip figures
$ ls figures
./  ../  figure1.png  figure2.png
$ pdflatex test.tex
.............
Output written on test.pdf (2 pages, 52581 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Interestiong. Hadn't thought of that. I'm primarily on Windows, and it looks like `fuse-zip` wouldn't work there, but apparently there are several other options: http://superuser.com/questions/367540/tool-to-mount-a-zip-rar-archive-as-a-win-drive-and-be-able-to-read-write-as-a